# variable not working globally with jQuery, need to be define inside the function, why?

Tags: jquery

I have this snippet

```
  let bgColor;
  let toolColor;

  let brushTool = $('.fa-paint-brush');

  // Build the Grid
  CREATE_CANVAS_FORM.submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Show good popups
    CREATE_GRID_POPUP.addClass('hidden');
    CANVAS_TABLE.removeClass('hidden');

    // Build the grid
    makeGrid();

    // Setup the grid
    bgColor = BG_COLOR_GRID.val();
    toolColor = TOOL_COLOR_GRID.val();

    CANVAS_TABLE.css('background-color', bgColor);
    BACK_COLOR.val(bgColor);
    TOOL_COLOR.val(toolColor);

    // Select the brush tool
    brushTool.addClass('selected-tool');
  });
```

The variables bgColor and toolColor are working fine but not the brushTool one. I need this variable in another function so I can't define it inside this one.

This is the only one variable which doesn't work, and I need to put the line `let brushTool = $('.fa-paint-brush');` inside the function to make it work.

Can anyone help me to figure out why? And maybe give me a hint to define my variable globally?

Here is the full code: https://codepen.io/maevanapcontact/pen/Gybaqv
The function starts at line 275, the corresponding HTML elements are the fontawesome brush which should become orange when the class is added.

To run the function:
click on the green plus circle > click on the button "create canvas"

Comment: Have you tried any of my suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JQuery selector is working just fine.  The problem you are facing is font awesome is replacing the `<i>` element with an `<svg>` element so your brushTool variable now refers to an element that doesn't exist on the DOM.

See https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js for reference.

You could write a function that returns the element on demand and use that when you need it.

```
function getBrushTool() {
    return $(".fa-paint-brush");
}
```

Or you could wrap the `<i class="fa-paint-brush">` inside another element and give the outer element an id that you could access and modify in your js instead.

EDIT:
You could also add this to the top of your script to instruct font awesome to nest the element instead of replacing it.

```
FontAwesomeConfig = { autoReplaceSvg: 'nest' }
```

and finally update your css to target the svg.

```
.selected-tool svg {
    color: #e9722a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window` to declare variables and have them available in all scopes.  That variable will then be available in all functions at all times..  `var`  and `let` are limited in scope.  IE

```
window.brushTool = $('.fa-paint-brush');
```

At this point, you can use the variable `brushTool` anywhere.

Comment: While you can do this, its a terrible practice.

Comment: can you explain to me why it is not working? All the others are working

Comment: Because you have declared it **outside** the `CREATE_CANVAS_FORM.submit` function whereas everything else is declared **inside** the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try using LocalStorage

```
  localStorage.setItem('brushTool', '$(".fa-paint-brush")');
```

and get the value by,

```
var brushTool = localStorage.getItem('brushTool');
```